# Extend the height of a ListView element so that the text appear on multiple lines

Tags: android, android-listview, text-alignment

I am trying to develop an app which, in landscape mode, it splits the activity in 2 fragments. In the first fragment, I have a listView which contains an icon and some text. My problem is, if the text is long enough, the text is shortened and 3 dots appears so that it shows the text is longer than that.
How can I make the text extend on multiple rows so that the text is no longer shortened, but shown whole ?

I've searched for other answers, but I couldn't find any of them suiting.

The xml for each row looks like this:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/text_view"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
```

Thank you.

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: @Nilesh, I posted it.

Comment: android:singleLine="true" remove this line from textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after removing   `android:singleLine="true"` line

As it forcing textview to show only in one line

```
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="@string/text_view"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why i didn't saw that.

Comment: Welcome @Phantom, If answer is helpful could you accept it

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `TextView` to following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Dummy Text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:lines="2" <!-- put this line if you always want to show 2 lines -->
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxLines="2" <!-- max number of size... used when text is long -->
   />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, the text is put on multiple lines, but the problem is that the text is getting smaller and smaller, depending on the text size.

Comment: might be you fixed the size of your ListItem, so the text is getting shrunk. Try not to fix the height